# How can I display a DoubleProperty on my scene?

Tags: java, javafx

I want this totalSalesAmountProperty to display the value but even after it is updated, and has an actual value, it still doesn't display. I know this has a value because I system.out the getter method and I get a value. Why would that be happening?

```
Label lblTotalSales = new Label(String.valueOf(newSale.getTotalSalesAmount1()));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (what is the return type of `getTotalSalesAmount1()` ?? Here I consider it `double`)

```
Label lblTotalSales = new Label(" " + newSale.getTotalSalesAmount1());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the label's text property to the `totalSalesAmountProperty`:

```
label.textProperty().bind(totalSalesAmountProperty);
```

Then the label text will automatically update any time the totalSalesAmountProperty is modified.

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
Label lblTotalSales = new Label(String.valueOf(newSale.getTotalSalesAmount1()));
```

you set the text to the `String` returned by `String.valueOf(newSale.getTotalSalesAmount1())` just before calling the `Label` constructor, i.e. it yields the same result as

```
String s = String.valueOf(newSale.getTotalSalesAmount1());
Label lblTotalSales = new Label(s);
```

`String`s are neither mutable nor observable in java and therefore the text is not automatically updated.

To fix this bind the `textProperty` of the `Label` to the `String` version of the `DoubleProperty`. This will add listeners to the property that will update the text of the `Label` every time the `DoubleProperty` changes.

```
DoubleProperty propertyToShow = ...
Label label = new Label();
label.textProperty().bind(propertyToShow.asString());
```